# Bokeh: Deprecated user-defined data source AND iterable values to glyph methods warning

Tags: python-2.7, bokeh

I have a graph with vbars in it, relevant piece of code:

```
fig = figure(title="Vbars", x_range=FactorRange(factors=coi[lab].tolist()))
fig.y_range.start = 0
fig.vbar(x="x", width=0.5, legend=False, source=source)
```

I used to have

```
fig.vbar(x=coi[lab], width=0.5, legend=False, source=source)
```

and wanted to get rid of the deprecation warning that stems from both supplying x and source-values. I can't instantiate a vbar-glyph without giving an x-value. How do I solve this? Can I somehow say that the x-column is contained in source? Or do I ignore the warning?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the x column in the source:

```
source.data['x'] = coi[lab]
fig.vbar('x', width=0.5, legend=False, source=source)
```

If you need a different name for some reason, that's fine:

```
source.data['foo'] = coi[lab]
fig.vbar('foo', width=0.5, legend=False, source=source)
```

You should not ignore the deprecation warning, as this usage will generate a hard error (exception) in the very near future.